# Autopublish removed but why can I still retrieve data from db?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database

I have a simple Meteor/MongoDB project using the 'roles' package where I optain data from the db to the client. The roles package seems to work fine and the browser shows the right data depending on who is logged in, just like it should do. Then when running 'meteor remove autopublish' in the terminal inside my applications directory I get 'autopublish removed' just like it should. Still I can retrieve data from the server just as before(!?)

I have all of my db calls from the client/client.js.

The server/server.js does nothing (I do have publish/subscribe code but uncomment for now) and same goes for the common js file in main directory.

How can this be? Am I perhaps retrieving data from minimongo somehow? I have also removed insecure even if I don't think that matters in this case(?) Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here's the code:

client.js:

```
//when uncomment the subscribe's you should not get access to the server/db, but 'data' that holds all the inlogg info still shows. The 'movies' on the other hand doesn't, just like it shouldn't. 

//Meteor.subscribe('data'); 

//Meteor.subscribe('movies');

/*############# Get User Data ###############*/

Template.userLoggedIn.id = function () { 
   return Meteor.userId();
};

Template.userLoggedIn.email = function () {
   var email = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
   return email.emails[0].address;
};

Template.userLoggedIn.profile = function () { 
   var profile = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
   return profile.profile.name;
};

Template.userLoggedIn.role = function () { 
   var role = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
   return role.roles[0];
};

/*#############  ###############*/

Template.movies.movies = function() {
   var movies = Movies.find().fetch();
  return movies;
}

server.js:

Meteor.publish('data', function () {
      return Meteor.users.find();
});

Meteor.publish('movies', function() {
      return Movies.find();
});
```

Comment: removing `autopublish` will reload your app, which will then clear out your minimongo data. It's really hard to answer this without seeing the code. What does `meteor list --using` show? You may also want to double check that those publish functions are actually commented out.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
This is what the terminal is listing:

standard-app-packages
accounts-password
roles
accounts-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing the code - I see how this could be confusing. The [users](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users) section of the docs should be written to explicitly say this, but what's happening is the **current user is always published**. So even if you don't write a publish function for users (or your have your subscribe commented out), you should expect to see the current user on the client. Because your template code only looks for `Meteor.userId()`, I would expect it to still work.

Assuming you have other users in the database, you can quickly check that they are not being published by running: `Meteor.users.find().count()` in your browser console. If it returns `1` then you are only publishing the current user (or `0` if you are logged out).

Comment: Ok, I tried to publish the other users but just like you said, only the current user is published. Thank you so very much.

Comment: Great! I'm glad we got that figured out. If you found this answer helpful, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).